# Why no audit in the low-quality queue at times?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, low-quality-posts

I have just noticed that the audit comes not so oftentimes in my opinion in the low-quality review queue, at least.

Today, I have reviewed 20 posts without getting a single audit, but it sometimes happens so for a couple of days. Lately, I have been reviewing 20 posts every day when I can, but sometimes it takes me a couple of days to meet an audit.

I personally think everyone should meet at least one audit per 20-40 posts as it is 2.5-5%. Is this deliberately intentional?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally, roughly 5% of your reviews should be audits. Reviewers who *never* fail audits will get significantly less, and reviewers who *repeatedly* fail audits will get noticeably more.

But there's a bit of chance to it as well, and since we're not running a casino here that chance can and does influence the *actual* percentage. As a result, out of your past 1000 reviews only 4.1% have been audits.